# Remove file type from string

Tags: c#, string

I'm calling a list of strings from a server.

At the moment I'm getting the full name and file extension like:

> Image1.jpg
>
> image2.png
>
> test_folder.folder

I have some code that relies on the knowing what the extension is, however I also need to access the name of the item I've selected with out the extension.

So far my two attempts have been the following:

```
_clickedFolder = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() - "folder";
_clickedFolder.Trim(new Char[] { '.folder' });
```

but neither of these work.

What is the correct way to take the file extension away and just have the file name display?

Comment: @Sean Its seems like we are doing your homework step by step ?

Comment: @MauricioGracia I agree with you,Sean asked two question in no more than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 17):

Use the [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) class:

```
string fnWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
```

or

```
string extension = Path.GetExtension(path);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
string name = "set this to file name";
name = name.Substring(0,name.LastIndexOf('.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
    private void listBox1_SelectionIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
    string item = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    int index = item.LastIndexOf('.');
    if (index >= 0)//It's a valid file
    {
        string filename = item.Substring(0, index );
        MessageBox.Show(filename);
    }
    else if (index == -1)//Not a valid file
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The selected file is invalid.");
    }
    }
```